# String instance of a class that contains operations on data as well as Strings

Tags: haskell

I want to use Haskell custom operators in an application that involves arranging text and objects on an image. For instance, I'll have an operator that does vertical composition: placing one element above another. Let's call it |||.

Let's declare a data type Element to represent visual objects. One kind of visual element might be some text as specified in a string. Visually, this creates the words in some default font and size. Another kind of visual element might be a JPEG file. So we have

```
type Filename = String

data Element = EString String
             | EJpeg Filename
             | EVerticalComposition Element Element
```

I could declare the ||| operator as follows:

```
(|||) :: Element -> Element -> Element
```

However, for brevity I want to write something like this

```
composedElem = "some words" ||| "some words that appear below" 
               ||| "and more words"
```

Note that I don't want to have to add an EString in front of each string.

So I think I need ||| to be part of a typeclass that includes a String instance as well as an Element instance. I might have something like this:

```
class ImageClass a where
    (|||) :: a -> a -> a

instance ImageClass String where
    (|||) x y = EVerticalComposition x y
```

But assuming `(|||)` is left-associative and I use it in expressions of several terms such as above, I also need `(|||)` to operate sometimes on Elmeents, like

```
(|||) :: Element -> String -> Element
```

Is this even possible? Or, if so, is it worth it? I could also write my little program like this:

```
composedElem = EString "some Words" ||| "some words that appear below"
               ||| "and more words"
```

But what about putting other kinds of elements with `(|||)`? I didn't want to put a constructor in front of everything, just for the sake of brevity, unless this is too complicated to implement.

Comment: Have you tried [overloaded strings](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings)?

Comment: When you find yourself writing a function with signature `a -> a -> a`, you should probably just declare a [monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html) instance.

Comment: By the way, what you are describing is the haskell `diagram` library.

Comment: Do you mean `diagrams`? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams

Comment: @composerMike: Almost definitely. It's an awesome library! Take a look at their [project page](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/), which has more detail than the Hackage page.

Comment: my only issue is that what I'm doing involves lengthy and moderately complex animations, which are probably hard to specify in a general language but require only a few quirky features if I program them myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be likely to use a class for converting custom types to an `Element`, and then have the operator `|||` take generic parameters of that class.

Eg:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Main where
type Filename = String

data Element = EString String
             | EJpeg Filename
             | EVerticalComposition Element Element
  deriving (Show)



class AsElement a where
  toElement :: a -> Element

instance AsElement Element where
  toElement = id
instance AsElement String where
  toElement = EString

(|||) :: (AsElement a, AsElement b) => a -> b -> Element
a ||| b = EVerticalComposition (toElement a) (toElement b)

infixl 4 |||




testElement1 :: Element
testElement1 = "this" ||| "that"

testElement2 :: Element
testElement2 = "this" ||| EJpeg "lol" ||| "another"
```

Results:

```
λ> testElement1
EVerticalComposition (EString "this") (EString "that")
λ> testElement2
EVerticalComposition (EVerticalComposition (EString "this") (EJpeg "lol")) (EString "another")
```

You could add more types just by adding more instances of `AsElement`.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the basic idea I was hunting for. This resembles GHC OverloadedStrings as mentioned in an earlier comment.